# Column set to `\textwidth` is wider than general text on the page

Tags: tables, geometry, textwidth

In the following example, I'm dumping some lorem ipsum text into the output to have some sense of the `\textwidth`. Then I create a simple table, and set its first column equal to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Vacancy details}
        \label{table:scientific-software-engineer}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}|c|}
            \hline
            Item & Information \\
            \hline
            \hline
            Location & Eindhoven \\
            \hline
            Experience & 3-5 years \\
            \hline
            Recruiter name & Bob \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Rendering the pdf output with `latexmk -pdflatex table.tex` shows that the column for which I have explicitly set the width is wider than the `\textwidth`.

Why does this occur and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You also need to take into account the width of the c column (tricky!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong I suppose, but the total width of the column will also include a `\tabcolsep` of padding at each end, if I remember/understand correctly. You can subtract that by using `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}`. (Note: if your document loads the `array` package, then you may need to subtract the width of the vertical rules as well: `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}`)

Alternatively you can remove that padding by setting `\tabcolsep` to 0pt, or for that specific column with `@{}p{\textwidth}@{}` (this won't look good though). The `@{}` replaces the space at the start/end of the column with whatever you add in the braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-4]
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Vacancy details}
        \label{table:scientific-software-engineer}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|c|}
            \hline
            Item & Information \\
            \hline
            \hline
            Location & Eindhoven \\
            \hline
            Experience & 3-5 years \\
            \hline
            Recruiter name & Bob \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        
        \begin{tabular}{|@{}p{\textwidth}@{}|c|}
            \hline
            Item & Information \\
            \hline
            \hline
            Location & Eindhoven \\
            \hline
            Experience & 3-5 years \\
            \hline
            Recruiter name & Bob \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, my previous comment was wrong. Please ignore. (It would have been correct if the `array` package was loaded -- which is not the case in your test code. If you want to be totally ODC about it, you could mention that if the `array` package were loaded, one would need to subtract `2`\arrayrulewidth` as well.)

Comment: @Mico  Just had the same thought after looking at the output with `showframe`. Ignored :) (will delete this comment soon)

Comment: Is `\relax` necessary here? I was able to run it fine without

Comment: @user32882 Not 100% sure to be honest. I think it's usually needed to "end" a `\dimexpr` calculation, but perhaps it's redundant in this case. Someone else would have to answer that.

Comment: `\relax` tells `\dimexpr` to stop adding terms.  `{\dimexpr ...}` also works.